# Can we programmatically check that is our variable name in standard form or not.?

Tags: java, reflection

Example

```
class MyClass {

    String name;
    String NAme;
    public static void main(String args[]) {

    }
}
```

Output should be:

```
name is in standard form
NAme is not in standard form
```

Comment: look at `checkstyle`?

Comment: you can use the checksyle plugin for eclipse https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/checkstyle-plug.

Comment: What about a `BMWCarFactory`? Is your standard form `bmwCarFactory` or `bMWCarFactory` and what's the algorithm to decide that? (hint: good luck finding that)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its possible through *reflection*.You can get all the declared fields using:-

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Field[] fields = MyClass.class.getDeclaredFields();
    for(Field field : fields ){
    field.setAccessible(true);
    String name = field.getName();
    //Check if name contains small letters or the logic to check if camel-case etc
    }
}
```

You cannot do this for local variables